# Changing locale from en_US.utf8 to en_US in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, gnome, gnome-terminal, locale

I'm installing "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 (Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015)"

I am trying to switch from `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` to `LANG="en_US"` as we need to operate the OS in 8 bits ASCII mode.

I have tried to change `/etc/locale.conf` and reboot.

It doesn't work for gnome. For instance, when I try to launch a terminal session, I get this error:

```
Dec 23 14:27:56 cmt22 gnome-session: Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server exited with status 8
```

Accordingly to [gnome documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#Exit_status_8), it says the locale is not defined but `localectl list-locales` shows it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Some forwards:

- RHEL 7 as opposed to 5 *defaults* to the utf8 character encoding. So in RHEL5, you could do 'en_US' and you'd still be in ASCII. Now you're in utf8.
- Unfortunately, all man pages are now in utf8 and the man page system
  sorta forces you to use it. You will have trouble viewing some man pages with a non-utf8 encoding unless you hammer away at the `nroff` program and `man.config`
- 8-bit ASCII is *de facto* replaced with iso-8859-1, which lacks a few things that are fixed by iso-8859-15.

You can override the character encoding by replacing `UTF-8` with `iso-8859-1` or perhaps `iso-8859-15`.  Update `/etc/locale.conf` (in <7, `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`) or set it per-user in `$HOME/.i18n`.

```
LANG=en_US.iso-8859-15
```

Test on the command line first (using `export LANG...`) and then run `locale` to make sure there are no errors (it will complain if so).

Comment: sorry, I tried with en_US.iso885915 but I get the same issue into gnome.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific. and fix some mistakes. Re-read and try again?

Comment: Worst case: set LANG=C and re-start gnome. Are you running GNOME as a system desktop? Do you know how to relaunch it without rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

You need an UTF8 locale for `gnome-terminal` to work properly in the recent version of GNOME